# Adding Search Query and Link that was clicked to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using the [Tutorial](http://youhack.me/2010/04/28/creating-a-fancy-search-feature-with-php-mysql-and-jquery/) to create a search engine. I've got it to do the searching. But now I'm trying to get it to insert the links the user has clicked and the search query they used into another db table. 
I'm having trouble doing this.

I see right here

```
include_once ('database_connection.php');//Including our DB Connection file
if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){//IF the url contains the parameter "keyword"
 $keyword =     trim($_GET['keyword']) ;//Remove any extra  space
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $keyword);//Some validation

$query = "select topictitle,topicdescription from topics where topictitle like '%$keyword%' or topicdescription like '%$keyword%'";
//The SQL Query that will search for the word typed by the user .

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);//Run the Query
if($result){//If query successfull
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)!=0){//and if atleast one record is found
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ //Display the record
                        $image = '';
                    switch( $row['Carrier'] ) {
                        case 'Nextel(Sprint)':
                            $image = './images/rat.png';
                            break;
                        case 'Verizon':
                            $image = './images/dog.png';
                            break;
                        case 'Sprint':
                            $image = './images/rooster.png';
                            break;
                        case 'AT&T(also Cingular)':
                            $image = './images/ox.png';
                            break;
                        case 'T-Mobile':
                            $image = './images/snake.png';
                            break;
                        case 'Tiger':
                            $image = './images/tiger';
                            break;
    }
                    echo '<table><tr><td>We Think your Number is </td><td><a href="next.php?csv='.$row['Carrier'].'">
                    <img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$row['Carrier'].'" title="'.$row['Carrier'].'" /></a></td><td> Is that correct? <a href="">Yes</a> Or 
                    <a href="#" id="button" class="button_style">No</a></td></tr></table>
                    <div id="hidden_content">
                        <ul><!-- IF user clicks one of these links it will direct them to the page then insert there search query and the link they clicked into a database
                            <li><a href="next.php?rat"><img src="./images/rat.png" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="next.php?dog"><img src="./images/dog.png" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="next.php?rooster"><img src="./images/rooster.png" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="next.php?ox"><img src="./images/ox.png" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="next.php?snake"><img src="./images/snake.png" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="next.php?tiger"><img src="./images/tiger.png" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>';
 }
 }else {
 echo 'No Results for :"'.$_GET['keyword'].'"';//No Match found in the Database
 }

}
}else {
 echo 'Parameter Missing in the URL';//If URL is invalid
}
```

My problem is I'm trying to get it so when the user clicks a link the link that gets clicked and gets inserted into the database as well as the query the user typed. But I can't figure out how to do this

Comment: so, you don't have a question. huh?

Comment: I can try to help but what search query are you talking about?  Inserting the link they click on is simple enough by getting it from the url of the next page.